# Combine multiple selection and search autocomplete features in a data validation dropdown list

Tags: excel, vba, dropdown, autosuggest, multipleselection

I have a data validation dropdown list for which I use the below macro to enable multiple selection. I need to combine it with a search autocomplete feature like for a Web search engine.

For example:

1. I type first "Ban", then it will check in the data validation list all the words containing "ban" and the dropdown list is shortened to have only the matching words. I select the word "Banana" and it is now displayed in the cell.
2. Then type the word "berry" and the dropdown list is shortened to only the matching words. I select the word "Strawberry" and now the text displayed in the cell is "Banana, Strawberry".

[image: List]

[image: Data validation with multiple selection feature (only)]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'That code is for the multiple selection. It allows the user to select multiple items one by one in the dropdown list. Then they will be separated by one coma.
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String

Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub

If Target.Address = "$E$3" Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

'== SOURCE ==
'https://trumpexcel.com/select-multiple-items-drop-down-list-excel/
```

So far, I succeeded through a tutorial without VBA to apply a search autocomplete feature. I then tried to modify the formulas to make the search autocomplete only consider the text next to the last coma (on the right). From my attempt, I have a feeling it is better to have a full VBA solution for that but I'm clueless on the way to do it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might want to add what this VBA code you posted does.

Comment: The code you posted is only for managing the multi-select thing. You need also to show how you managed the autocomplete feauture. This part is completely missing. Please read [mcve]. We need to be able to reproduce what you have done.

Comment: The code is for multiple selection: select in one cell multiple items and they will be separated by comas. For the autocomplete feature I did not used VBA but formulas (Chester Tugwell video). I tried to combine/modify both of them it became a huge mess and it is everything but helping to see what I did. For my issue in general, if you even have some guidance not necessarily related to the code I provided it is welcome. I will check it swiftly. My problem now is I do not even know where to start with VBA for that specific issue and so the minimal reproducible example is still out of reach :'(